# Converting Ruby array into a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am attempting to write a method named `my_transform` that takes an array as follows:

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]
```

and displays the items' indexes as follows:

```
item_to_position = {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

I should be able to execute:

```
my_transform(items) == item_to_position
```

and receive `true`.

I have contemplated using `each_with_index`. Should I begin by saying:

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]

hash = Hash[*array]

def my_transform
```

I have to convert the string to a hash. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in the section starting with "I have contemplated" makes much sense to me, I'm afraid.  The body of `my_transform` is missing... does it contain code we should see?  Also, "I have to convert the string to a hash" is the first mention of any string manipulation in the question.  What string?

Answer (score 11):

I would use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]
items.each_with_index.to_h
#=> { "Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4 }
```

Note that `to_h` was introduced in Ruby 2.1

Using `to_h` your `my_transform` method could look like this:

```
def my_transform(items)
  items.each_with_index.to_h
end
```

Comment: This is actually [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) and the documentation includes this as an example ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in various ways.

**Create an array and convert it to a hash**

Until fairly recently, you would use the public class method [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html) to convert an array to a hash. It works like this:

```
h = Hash[ [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]] ]
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

or

```
h = Hash[:a, 1, :b, 2]
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

In Ruby v2.1.0 the methods [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) and [Enumerable#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) were introduced. The first works like this:

```
h = [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]].to_h
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Therefore, to use `Hash` or `to_h` you must first create the array:

```
arr1 = [["Aqua", 0], ["Blue", 1], ["Green", 2], ["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 4]]
```

or

```
arr2 = ["Aqua", 0, "Blue", 1, "Green", 2, "Red", 3, "Yellow", 4]
```

In the second case we'd use it like this:

```
Hash[*arr2]
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

Let's first create `arr1`. You are right that you need to use [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index). You then need to use [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) to convert each element of `items` to an array `[<color>, index]`.

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]

arr = items.each_with_index.to_a
  #=> [["Aqua", 0], ["Blue", 1], ["Green", 2], ["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 4]]
```

Let's look at this more closely:

```
enum = items.each_with_index 
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]:each_with_index>
```

`enum`, an enumerator, is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html). The `Enumerator` class is one of many classes that `include`s the `Enumerable` module, of which `to_a` is an instance method. Not only does:

```
arr = enum.to_a
  #=> [["Aqua", 0], ["Blue", 1], ["Green", 2], ["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 4]]
```

convert the enumerator to the desired array, but it is a convenient way to view the elements of any enumerator (which are generally passed to either a block or to another enumerator).

So we can now create the hash:

```
h = Hash[arr]   
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

or

```
h = Hash[*arr.flatten]
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

or

```
h = arr.to_h
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

Suppose now that we had:

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Aqua", "Aqua"]
```

We then obtain:

```
items.each_with_index.to_a.to_h
  #=> {"Aqua"=>4, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2}
```

In building the hash, Ruby first creates the key-value pair `"Aqua"=>0`, which she later overwrites with `"Aqua"=>3` and then with `"Aqua"=>4`. This is a consequence of the fact that hashes have unique keys.

**Build the hash from scratch**

Now suppose we start with an empty hash:

```
h = {}
```

(same as `h = Hash.new`) and add key-value pairs:

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]
items.each_index { |i| h[items[i]] = i }
  #=> ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"] 
h #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

We could alternatively write:

```
items.size.times { |i| h[items[i]] = i }
  #=> 5
h #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

or

```
(0...items.size).each { |i| h[items[i]] = i }
  #=> 0...5 
h #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

The Ruby way is skip the step `h = {}` and to use `each_with_index`, as before, together with [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object):

```
items.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(s,i),h| h[s] = i }
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

The "object" in `with_object` is a hash, `with_object`'s argument being its initial value, here an empty hash. This object is represented by the block variable `h` and is returned after all elements of `items` have been enumerated (so we don't need a subsequent line `h` to return the hash).

Lets look at the steps that are performed here. First, we have

```
enum0 = items.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]:each_with_index>
```

which I discussed earlier. Then Ruby computes

```
enum1 = enum0.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]
        :each_with_index>:with_object({})>
```

Examine the return value carefully. As you see, `enum1`, like `enum0`, is an enumerator. You might think of it as a "compound enumerator". To see the values of `enum1` that will be passed to the block, you can convert it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[["Aqua", 0], {}], [["Blue", 1], {}], [["Green", 2], {}],
  #    [["Red", 3], {}], [["Yellow", 4], {}]]
```

As you see, `enum1` has five elements, each an array containing an array and a hash. The elements of `enum1` are passed to the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), (which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)):

```
enum1.each { |(s,i),h| h[s] = i }
  #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to pass each element of `enum1` to the block, and set the block variables to its value. The first is:

```
(s,i),h = enum1.next
  #=> [["Aqua", 0], {}] 
s #=> "Aqua" 
i #=> 0 
h #=> {}
```

Notice how `[["Aqua", 0], {}]` is decomposed into its three constituent elements and each block variable is set equal to one of the elements. This is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

We can now perform the block calculation:

```
h[s] = i
 #=> {}["Aqua"] = 0
```

so now:

```
h #=> {"Aqua"=>0}
```

Then the second element is passed to the block:

```
(s,i),h = enum1.next
  #=> [["Blue", 1], {"Aqua"=>0}] 
  s #=> "Blue" 
  i #=> 1 
  h #=> {"Aqua"=>0}
```

Notice how `h` has been updated. The block calculation is now:

```
h[s] = i
 #=> {"Aqua"=>0}["Blue"] = 1
```

and now:

```
h #=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1}
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly. After all elements of `enum1` have been enumerated, `enum1.each` returns `h`.

Comment: Excellent, Cary. I really appreciate you taking the time to fully explain the array, hash, and enum. It is much, much clearer!

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_transform(arr)
  arr.inject({}) {|m,e| m[e] = arr.index(e); m }
end
```

Comment: @Stefan Well, isn't that because haha keys are unique?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel oh, of course! :-) (well, unless `compare_by_identity` is set)

Comment: You can get rid of that pesky `; m` by using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object): `arr.each_with_object({}) {|e,m| m[e] = arr.index(e) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]
def my_transform(items)     
   Hash[items.each_with_index.map { |value, index| [value, index] }]
end
```

Comment: `Hash[items.each_with_index.to_a]` should be sufficient.

Comment: @ArieShaw: oh yeah thats even better! thanks for pointing out :)!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

**e.g.**

```
items = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]

items.inject({}) do |tmphash, (k,v)|
  tmphash[k] = items.index(k)
  tmphash
end

## OUTPUT

{"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}
```

Comment: Why do you call `group_by(&:itself)`? What's the benefit of building a `{"Aqua"=>["Aqua"], "Blue"=>["Blue"], ...}` hash?

Comment: I used it to group duplicate values.

Comment: I'd use `uniq` to remove duplicates from an array, but I'm not even sure this is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

### Most Rubies

This works at least as far back as Ruby 1.9.3.

```
# Verbose, but flexible!
def hasherize *array
  hash = {}
  array.flatten!
  array.each_with_index { |key, value| hash[key] = value }
  hash
end

# Pass a single array as an argument.
hasherize %w(Aqua Blue Green Red Yellow)
#=> {"Aqua"=>0, "Blue"=>1, "Green"=>2, "Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>4}

# Pass multiple arguments to the method.
hasherize :foo, :bar, :baz
#=> {:foo=>0, :bar=>1, :baz=>2}
```

### Ruby >= 2.1.0

If you're running a recent Ruby, you can simplify the above to:

```
def hasherize *array
  array.flatten.each_with_index.to_h
end
```

The results will be the same as above, but the [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method simplifies the code a lot. However, you still need to flatten the array to avoid results like:

```
#=> {["Aqua", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]=>0}
```

Comment: Why do you call `flatten`?

Comment: `Hash[array.each_with_index.to_a]` will work with Ruby 1.9.3